# interfacing pic with lcd screen

Tags: c, pic, lcd

Hello I'm trying to figure out a way to connect my pic16f1823 to a lcd screen, but the problem with my lcd screen there are no data lines so no D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6,D7 and no E,RS,R/W. All I have one the lcd is LED+, LED-, RST,SCL,SDA and the normal power lines. So I wanted to know if anyone has every used lcd like mine and point me in the right direction, if you could also provide so resources that you have used for this specific lcd screen with pic that would be helpful as well.

Comment: Almost any of the close reasons apply here.

Comment: https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/i2c

Comment: Well, the data sheet for the LCD panel would help a lot, I suspect, and tell you how to interface with it, though @markgz has caught the bus.

Comment: Because your LCD panel interface is I2C, not the GPIO (parallel port) one. You need to connect it to free I2C host. LED+ and LED- pins are connected to backlight, while RST (reset) line is just a global reset for it (needs GPIO).

Comment: @0andriy then what do the SDL and SCL ports do because I'm still having trouble figuring out how to code this

Comment: It's **i2c** hardware interface! Read the specification and other documentation if in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Your LCD uses a I2C interface as noted  0andriy.

The LCD itself is built by a manufacturer and probably have a product ID. The LCD itself contains a Chip (you cannot see it since it's integrated) that is produced by other manufacturer.

This chip control the actual LCD panel, and it is this chip datasheet that you need in order to have it working.

Once you get that datasheet, you can probably find some code sample on the internet. Not that often these Chips uses quite close commands.

Common chip for LCD are ILI and ESP chips.

Without knowing which chip is inside your LCD panel, it will be difficult to have it working as you will have to know the I2C configuration, I2C address, the registries addresses and values to control the LCD.